# Do unused data in Elasticsearch reduce performance?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch server with logs data, right now I have 3 year data (50 GB). I have checked that, data older than 1 year is rarely required.

If I change all the queries to fetch the data only for last 1 year, how it impact the performance? Or should I store data older than 1 year on another server?

I Did some digging but could not find the exact answer.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html

Comment: Querying less indices, hence less data, will certainly have a positive impact on performance. Just point your queries at your latest index and you'll see. You should also [consider using aliases](https://www.elastic.co/blog/aliases-ftw) so that you don't need to change your code when a new index is created.

Comment: @Val can u please tell me how it will impact the performance?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing your exact setup (hardware, document count, etc) and the queries you're running. It's just common sense, since you query less data, the performance can only get better and not worse